# Difference betwen org.wildfly.bom and org.jboss.spec for Java EE7 with maven

Tags: maven, jboss, dependencies, java-ee-7, wildfly

I am working in a new project that is going to use Java EE 7 with WildFly, but I am still confused about which maven dependencies I should use.
I have found these two groups that apparently I can use: org.wildfly.bom and org.jboss.spec

They have the following predefined artifact to use in the projects (searched in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#welcome):

org.wildfly.bom:

- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools
- jboss-bom-parent
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-transactions
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-security
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-resteasy
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-infinispan
- jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate3

org.jboss.spec:

- jboss-javaee-all-7.0
- jboss-javaee-web-7.0
- jboss-javaee-7.0

Also I have realized that that I can see dependency Hierarchy using  org.jboss.spec but not with wildfly.bom. So, my question is what is the difference?, which one do you suggest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `org.wildfly.bom` includes dependencies for the versions of Hibernate, RESTEasy, etc. as well as their dependencies that are used in WildFly. For if you use Jackson2 annotations the `org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-resteasy` should include the correct version of the Jackson2 dependency.

The `org.jboss.spec` only include the Java EE 7 API's used.

If you're not using anything specific to WildFly then I would use the `org.jboss.spec` BOM. If you're using something specific that the server includes, like Jackson2, Infinispan, etc., then I'd use the `org.wildfly.bom`.

Comment: Thanks, I even realized that wildfly.bom includes org.jboss.spec dependency.